# Model is hashable and Identifiable but still can't use ForEach

Tags: swift

I've been at it for more than 8h refactoring the code over and over again and I can't get it to work, I have this in my view:

```
ForEach(allWalletsData.walletList) { walletKey in
    WalletStackView(user: user, walletAddress: walletKey)
}
```

and it complains saying: `value of type 'String' has no member 'walletList'`
if I try another combination like:

```
ForEach(allWalletsData.walletList) { walletKey in
    WalletStackView(user: user, walletAddress: walletKey)
}
```

it says: `referencing initializer 'init(_:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'String' conform to 'Identifiable'`

The data comes from a Publisher:

```
@Published var allWalletsData: AllWalletsData = AllWalletsData(walletList: [], walletsData: [:], combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted: "")
```

In my model I've wrote it 1000 different ways and still... doesn't work.

> The information in it cannot be static, as I refresh the API, the data will change.

This is the model I've tried:

```
struct AllWalletsData: Decodable, Encodable {
    init(walletList: [String], walletsData: OrderedDictionary<String, WalletInformation>, combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted: String) {
        self.walletList = walletList
        self.walletsData = walletsData
        self.combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted = combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted
    }

    let walletList: [String]
    let walletsData: OrderedDictionary<String, WalletInformation>
    let combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted: String
}

extension AllWalletsData: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: [String] { walletList }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted)
    }

    static func ==(lhs: AllWalletsData, rhs: AllWalletsData) -> Bool {
        if lhs.combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted != rhs.combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I've burned out at this point trying to find out what's happening, does anyone know what's going on?

EDIT:

Here's the second part of the model that contains the data using in the ForEach:

```
struct WalletInformation: Decodable, Encodable {
    init(wallet: Wallet, chainsInfo: [ChainReCalculatedData], allChainsTotalBalanceValue: String) {
        self.wallet = wallet
        self.chainsInfo = chainsInfo
        self.combinedChainsTokensQuotesFormatted = allChainsTotalBalanceValue
    }

    let wallet: Wallet
    let chainsInfo: [ChainReCalculatedData]

    // Combined chain balances
    let combinedChainsTokensQuotesFormatted: String
}

extension WalletInformation: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { wallet.address }

    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(wallet)
        hasher.combine(chainsInfo)
        hasher.combine(combinedChainsTokensQuotesFormatted)
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: WalletInformation, rhs: WalletInformation) -> Bool {
        if lhs.wallet != rhs.wallet {
            return false
        }
        if lhs.chainsInfo != rhs.chainsInfo {
            return false
        }
        if lhs.combinedChainsTokensQuotesFormatted != rhs.combinedChainsTokensQuotesFormatted {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us how you declare your `allWalletsData`
in your view where you have the `ForEach(allWalletsData.walletList)`.

Comment: it's coming from a Publisher `@Published var allWalletsData: AllWalletsData = AllWalletsData(walletList: [], walletsData: [:], combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted: "")` @workingdog

Comment: Nevertheless, it would help if you 
could show us how you declare `allWalletsData` in your view.
If it is coming from a publisher, then you should probably use the "model" such as: 
`ForEach(model.allWalletsData.walletList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making `AllWalletsData` `Identifiable`, you need to make the individual items of your collection `Identifiable` or `Hashable`, or provide an ID.

Your collection is `allWalletsData.walletList` -- according to your model, this is of type `[String]`. So, one option is:

```
ForEach(allWalletsData.walletList, id: \.self) { walletKey in
    WalletStackView(user: user, walletAddress: walletKey)
}
```

That tells SwiftUI to use the `String` as the `id` for each item (which looks like what you were trying to accomplish by doing `var id: [String] { walletList }`.

*Beware that if `walletAddress` doesn't contain truly unique elements, this (using `id: \.self`) can lead to unpredictable results. The other route to go would be defining a model for your wallet that had truly unique ids (like a `UUID`).*

---

**Update, based on comments:**

It sounds like instead of trying to store separate arrays of keys and dictionaries of your data, you should just have an array of your models. Something like:

```
struct WalletInformation : Identifiable, Codable {
 var id = //...
 //other properties
} 

struct AllWalletsData: Decodable, Encodable {
  var walletList : [WalletInformation]   
}

//and your ForEach:

ForEach(allWalletsData.walletList) { wallet in
    WalletStackView(user: user, wallet: wallet)
}
```

Comment: The type [String] was an idea to make it identifiable, that can change, it's actually extra that I don't need, if you see a better approach I can change it

Comment: Also the actual data is in `walletsData` which is the Dictionary with the stuff, the array of `walletList`  was an idea I had to use it as identifier and each item inside the array is unique, it contains a unique wallet address

Comment: The better approach is to give each item a truly unique ID, like I mentioned at the end. But, I don't have much information about how your data is stored, so it's hard to provide a concrete solution. I would expect, for example, that you'd have a `struct` called `Wallet` and then your view model would hold an array of Wallets -- `[Wallet]`. `Wallet` would have an `id` property and conform to `Identifiable`. This would be instead of storing everything in a Dictionary like you're doing now.

Comment: The data looks like this, I'm fetching the data and I'm doing calculations in the viewmodel and at the end I assign it to `@Published var allWalletsData: AllWalletsData = AllWalletsData(walletList: [], walletsData: [:], combinedWalletTokensQuotesFormatted: "")`

So the publisher gets everything already calculated, does that help?

Comment: No, none of this has anything to do with how you're fetching the data. Did you understand my idea about storing an array of `Wallet` or `WalletInformation` and having that conform to `Identifiable`? See my updated answer.

Comment: I think I understand. What you wrote there is similar to what I have, honestly I feel like a zombie now I may be missing something, but I am declaring it as Identifiable in the subview (see my edited block above)

Comment: What I have is *similar* but not the same as what you have. You were trying to use `ForEach` on `[String]`. I'm suggesting you use it on `[WalletInformation]`. I don't know what "declaring it as Identifiable in the subview" means. I see that `WalletInformation` is `Identifiable`, which is good.

Comment: but to get there I have first to iterate through they keys of the dictionary. Let's say I have 3 wallets so 3 Keys and each have 1000 values. See the challenge of why it's giving me the error? I need to loop through the keeys first to create 3 views, then in those views I can iterate through `[WalletInformation]`

Comment: Unfortunately, none of that is clear to me. What "3 views" are you talking about -- that's the first time it's been mentioned? Why do you need to iterate through the dictionary? What does that have to do with the compilation error? It looks like the question is about how to solve a syntax error with `ForEach`, but maybe it's not? Please try to include a [mre] as clearly there's an information breakdown somewhere here.